# Jenkins Service Start Fails due To bind(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:22) - failed to bind: Permission denied

Tags: jenkins

In our Jenkins Production environment we can't get Jenkins service running. It stuck at activating status. Below you can find severe log texts.

```
2024-02-18 10:47:37.985+0000 [id=56]    SEVERE  o.a.s.c.u.logging.LoggingUtils#error: bind(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:22) - failed (SocketException) to bind: Permission denied
2024-02-18 10:47:37.990+0000 [id=56]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed SSHD.init
2024-02-18 10:47:40.985+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  h.p.g.b.GlobalBuildStatsPluginSaver#reloadPlugin: Unable to read /hdd2/jenkins/global-build-stats.xml
2024-02-18 10:47:51.303+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  o.j.p.s.s.ScriptApproval$ApprovedWhitelist#<init>: Malformed signature entry in scriptApproval.xml: 'Method jenkins.model.Jenkins getItemByFullName'
2024-02-18 10:48:02.500+0000 [id=1093]  SEVERE  c.m.t.j.internal.auth.NativeAuth#nativeAuthConfigure: Could not load GSSAPI library, Kerberos authentication disabled.
```

And these are detailed log texts;

```
024-02-18 15:08:01.775+0000 [id=69]    INFO    j.a.PrioritySorterPlugin#init2: Sorting existing Queue ...
2024-02-18 15:08:01.787+0000 [id=69]    INFO    j.a.sorter.AdvancedQueueSorter#init: Initialized the QueueSorter with 0 Buildable Items
2024-02-18 15:08:01.790+0000 [id=74]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated
2024-02-18 15:08:01.800+0000 [id=1024]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Download metadata
2024-02-18 15:08:01.806+0000 [id=1024]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Download metadata. 3 ms
2024-02-18 15:08:01.841+0000 [id=110]   WARNING o.j.c.p.PersistentBuildQueue#getPersistentBuildQueueEntries: /hdd2/jenkins/org.jenkins.ci.plugins.PersistentBuildQueue.txt (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hdd2/jenkins/org.jenkins.ci.plugins.PersistentBuildQueue.txt (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.jenkins.ci.plugins.PersistentBuildQueue.getPersistentBuildQueueEntries(PersistentBuildQueue.java:111)
        at org.jenkins.ci.plugins.PersistentBuildQueue.load(PersistentBuildQueue.java:131)
        at org.jenkins.ci.plugins.PersistentBuildQueuePeriodicWork.doRun(PersistentBuildQueuePeriodicWork.java:43)
        at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:92)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2024-02-18 15:08:02.171+0000 [id=60]    INFO    h.p.s.ScmSyncConfigurationBusiness#queueChangeSet: Queue of changeset     A config.xml
 aborted (scm manipulator not settled !)
2024-02-18 15:08:02.214+0000 [id=90]    SEVERE  o.a.s.c.u.logging.LoggingUtils#error: bind(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:22) - failed (SocketException) to bind: Permission denied
2024-02-18 15:08:02.219+0000 [id=90]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed SSHD.init
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
        at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(AsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java:163)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor.bind(Nio2Acceptor.java:81)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor.bind(Nio2Acceptor.java:171)
        at org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer.start(SshServer.java:340)
        at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD.start(SSHD.java:180)
        at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD.init(SSHD.java:268)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.Error
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:115)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:185)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1156)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2024-02-18 15:08:04.296+0000 [id=93]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2024-02-18 15:08:04.352+0000 [id=30]    INFO    h.p.s.ScmSyncConfigurationBusiness#queueChangeSet: Queue of changeset     A config.xml
 aborted (scm manipulator not settled !)
2024-02-18 15:08:04.525+0000 [id=30]    WARNING j.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl#getWorkspaceRoot: JENKINS-2111 path sanitization ineffective when using legacy Workspace Root Directory ‘${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace’; switch to ‘${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}’ as in JENKINS-8446 / JENKINS-21942
2024-02-18 15:08:04.558+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  h.p.g.b.GlobalBuildStatsPluginSaver#reloadPlugin: Unable to read /hdd2/jenkins/global-build-stats.xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:583)
        at hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.model.JobBuildResultSharder.load(JobBuildResultSharder.java:143)
        at hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.xstream.migration.AbstractMigrator.readGlobalBuildStatsPOJO(AbstractMigrator.java:35)
        at hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.xstream.GlobalBuildStatsXStreamConverter.unmarshal(GlobalBuildStatsXStreamConverter.java:159)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
Caused: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.NullPointerException
cause-message       : null
class               : hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.GlobalBuildStatsPlugin
required-type       : hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.GlobalBuildStatsPlugin
converter-type      : hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.xstream.GlobalBuildStatsXStreamConverter
path                : /hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.GlobalBuildStatsPlugin
line number         : 2
version             : not available
-------------------------------
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:81)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:52)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:136)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1421)
        at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:190)
        at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:161)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1399)
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:196)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /hdd2/jenkins/global-build-stats.xml
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:199)
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:179)
        at hudson.Plugin.load(Plugin.java:271)
        at hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.GlobalBuildStatsPlugin.load(GlobalBuildStatsPlugin.java:102)
        at hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.business.GlobalBuildStatsPluginSaver.reloadPlugin(GlobalBuildStatsPluginSaver.java:99)
        at hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.business.GlobalBuildStatsBusiness.reloadPlugin(GlobalBuildStatsBusiness.java:395)
        at hudson.plugins.global_build_stats.GlobalBuildStatsPlugin$GlobalBuildStatsItemListener.onLoaded(GlobalBuildStatsPlugin.java:157)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:1034)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
```

We dont know why it tries to bind 22 port. Also it says "Unable to read /hdd2/jenkins/global-build-stats.xml", after recreation of this folder we are still getting this error. The folder ownerships are in jenkins user. But we run chown command and change all files to jenkins user again anyway. Didn't help us to solve it.
We are stuck with this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: wait, what? you don't know why it tries to use port 22 or you don't know why it can't bind to it? port 22 is probably already in use by sshd or you have to elevate privileges (ability to bind to a low-numbered port typically requires elevated privileges) , and it uses port 22 because you told it to.

Comment: My point was I had no idea why we got this error. I wrote this post in high stress situation some parts of it may not make sense. We fixed the issue by changing the jobs folder to jobsbak in jenkins folder. We started the services. It got up with zero jobs . We stoppeted the service then we changed the jobsbak to jobs. ıt got up again. So problem is solved this way but it still stucks at activating status when er restart the Jenkins. It might be related "java.io.IOException: Unable to read global-build-stats.xml" error. There are lots of xml's that Jenkins cannot read for some reason.